# To pass selected dropdown id to another component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular-services

I have an component called **list** where i am displaying all my `customers` names in the `dropdown` as shown below:

[image]

Now on `clicking/selecting` particular `item(i,e customer)` from the `dropdown` i want to emit that `id` to the `method/function` present in the another component called **display**.

display component code:

**TS file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ContactService } from '../contacts.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-display',
  templateUrl: './display.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./display.component.css']
})
export class DisplayComponent implements OnInit {
public contacts:any;
  constructor(private myService: ContactService) { }

public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
 this.contacts = await this.myService.getCustomersById('id');<=== Need to pass emitted customer id to here
}

}
```

- Now i am emitting the **ID** from the **list** component's dropdown.
- But i am unable to pass the emitted **id** to **services** file, and i am unable subscribe that **id** in **display** component.I have already created a **services** file. But i am unable to `communicate` using **services** file.

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-f91nvy?file=null)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changed your on click event from `(onSelectionChange)` to `(click)`.

HTML Code:

```
<div class="main-div">
<h3>List</h3>
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Select Customer">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let customer of customers" [value]="customer.id" (click)="selected($event, customer.id)">
      {{customer.customerName}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

TS Code:

```
public async selected(event: MatOptionSelectionChange, id: string): Promise<void> {
    this.myService.onCustomerSelect.next(id);
}
```

Service.ts:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ICustomer } from './models';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class ContactService {
 private  baseUrl : string = '../../assets/customers.json';

 onCustomerSelect: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


 public getCustomers(id : string): Promise<ICustomer> {
  const apiUrl: string = '../../assets/customers.json';

  return this.http.get<ICustomer>(apiUrl + id).toPromise();
}

public async getCustomersById(id : string): Promise<ICustomer[]> {
    const apiUrl: string = `${this.baseUrl}/${id}`;

    return this.http.get<ICustomer[]>(apiUrl).toPromise();
  }

}
```

[`UPDATED STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rafuy6)

EDIT:

you can call API like this:

```
public async ngOnInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.myService.onCustomerSelect.subscribe(value => {
      console.log('FROM Display Comp -----', value);
      this.CustId = value;
      if (this.CustId) {
        this.myService.getCustomersById(this.CustId).then(response =>{
          console.log(response)
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, still left with 1 issue.

Comment: How can i pass the id to this function **getCustomersById** of the `services` file?

Comment: @Shankar Like this:`this.myService.getCustomersById(this.CustId)`

Comment: I tried the same way but its showing as `undefined`.

Comment: Check out this:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-movie-read-load-json-sample-eg-rafuy6

Answer (score 1):

the best way to pass data to components that are not a parent or child is using the `Subject` from `rxjs`. I'll give you an example:

In your service create an instance of `Subject` like this:

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
static idChange: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>(false);
```

Now when you want to pass any data from the component that you have the id there, do this: (My service name is `GroupService`)

```
GroupService.idChange.next(value);
```

Then if you want to get the data in any component just subscribe to this `Subject` in `ngOnInit`. So when somewhere in your app you pass a value to that instance of `Subject`, you will get the data in anywhere you have subscribed to it.

```
GroupService.idChange.subscribe(id => {
      console.log('Got id: ', id);
});
```

Comment: Can please update in `stackblitz`, In the component where i am emitting `ID` when i type `services` **name(like: this.myService.idChange)** in the `vs code` it's not showing property name(idChange)